# android recyclerview крыть items(gone)

Tags: android, recyclerview

android recyclerview, есть список  n-элементов,  по нажатию  на последний item, скрываются  предыдущие items(gone), Я могу удалить из arrayList элементы и  обновить адаптер , но  мне дано скрывать и вновь  показывать эти items, Как это реализовать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вообще так делать, плохая идея, как по мне. Но кто я такой чтобы судить. Почему бы не показывать этот айтем вновом окне? 
Но если задача такова — простейшим решением было бы подменять адаптеры. Создайте один адаптер со списком из  n элементов и другой адаптер список которого пуст. При нажатии на какой то элемент, добавляйте его в лист второго адаптера, задавайте адаптер ресайклеру, готово. После нажатия на этот элемент задавайте обратно главный свой адаптер ресайклеру, чистите список с одним элементом. 
Такие манипуляции можно даже делать с анимашками, может получиться неплохо...